# What are the methods to pass Springboot/Thyleaf objects to Modal forms?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm confused. I've thought it's possible to pass SpringBoot/Thymeleaf objects from the html page to the Modal form. I've come across many examples using ajax to pull data from the REST endpoint instead.

Is using ajax to pull in objects into Modals, the only method?

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf is a server side templating language... the concept of a modal form usually means showing/hiding a window opens and closes on the client side (meaning JavaScript that runs when a user clicks a link or a button ).  If you don't want to use an API to pull that data (which I think makes the most sense), then you have to create a hidden modal for every row on your page. For example:

```
<div th:each="item, i: ${items}">
  <a href="#"
    onClick="openModal(this.getAttribute('data-modal'))"
    th:data-modal="|#modal${i.index}|">
    Edit modal #<span th:text="${i.index}" />
  </a>

  <div th:id="|modal${i.index}|" style="display: none;">
    <p>I am a modal form for element <span th:text="${i.index}" />!</p>
    <input type="text" th:value="${item.value}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see how this works... creating a hidden div/modal form for every row (so you don't have to call an API to get the form values), but it comes with a lot of extra HTML.